# Executing multiple spark queries and storing as dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 3 Spark queries saved in List - sqlQueries. The first 2 of them creates global temporary views and third one executes on those temporary views and fetches some output. 
I am able to run a single query using this -

```
val resultDF = spark.sql(sql)
```

Then I add partition information on this dataframe object and save it. 
In case of multiple queries, I tried executing

```
sqlQueries.foreach(query => spark.sql(query))
```

How do I save my output of third query keeping other 2 queries run. 
I have 3 queries just for example, It can be any number.

Comment: didn't https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213255/5880706 helped you ?

Comment: That helped in getting queries. How do i save it? Basically, if i save the final output, how do i make sure the queries have run before that.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the last query as insert statement to save the results into table. You are executing queries through foreach which will execute sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

I am taking reference from your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49212433/executing-multiple-sql-queries-on-spark) for the query which needs some modification as explained in [global-temporary-view](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#global-temporary-view) in sql section.

After *modification your query file should look like*

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY VIEW VIEW_1 AS select a,b from abc
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY VIEW VIEW_2 AS select a,b from global_temp.VIEW_1
select * from global_temp.VIEW_2
```

Then **answering this question**: you can use `foldLeft` again for the multiple queries to be reflected.

Lets say you have a `dataframe`

```
+----+---+---+
|a   |b  |c  |
+----+---+---+
|a   |b  |1  |
|adfs|df |2  |
+----+---+---+
```

And *given above multiple line query file*, you can do the following

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("abc")
val sqlFile = "path to test.sql"
val queryList = scala.io.Source.fromFile(sqlFile).getLines().filterNot(_.isEmpty).toList

val finalresult = queryList.foldLeft(df)((tempdf, query) => sqlContext.sql(query))
finalresult.show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+----+---+
|a   |b  |
+----+---+
|a   |b  |
|adfs|df |
+----+---+
```